# Can I compress this JavaScript object even more?

Tags: javascript, compression, uri

I have a 2D JS array of objects that I would like to compress as much as I can to possibly store the data into a query string that is encoded into a 64 bit URI component. So far I managed to compress my object into 2071 characters by storing the character code instead of a string, storing a number that identifies a color in the program instead of the hex codes, and shortening the object property names to one character.

```
var width = 33; //33 
var height = 18; //33
// make 2d array

var tree = new Array(height);

for(i=0; i<height; ++i){

    tree[i] = new Array(width);

}

// fill array with defaults

for(i=0; i<tree.length; ++i){

    for(j=0; j<tree[i].length; ++j){

        tree[i][j] = {
            s:0, // string char code
            c:[0], // color indices
            i:0, // current color index
            r:[0,0], // rate of animation
            b:2 // bgColor color index
        }

    }

}
```

I then stringify the object with json then I used the lz-string js library to create a compressed URI component string:

```
var treeStringified = JSON.stringify(tree);

var compressed = LZString.compressToEncodedURIComponent(treeStringified);
console.log(compressed);
console.log(compressed.length); 
string = LZString.decompressFromEncodedURIComponent(compressed);
console.log(string);
console.log(string.length);
```

So far the compressed URI component string ends up being 2071 characters with it's default "empty" values. Any way I can slim it down more?

Comment: Sounds like you should reconsider your approach. Only store needed data in your database.

Comment: Do you mean something like an SQL database? Because I'm not using anything like that. I just want to append the smallest amount of characters as a query string to a URL so when someone visits it, the program can decode it and create the object from the URL.

Comment: Are `height` and `width` constant? What are the ranges of `s`, `i`, `b`, and `c` and `r`'s elements? Is `r`'s length guaranteed to be 2?

Comment: Height and width is constant, but not stored in the tree object. The ranges of s is around 50, but could be more than 1000 if I choose to store other characters. Each element for c is 33 and less and you can store up to 6. i is 33 or less. R is 250 or less for each element of the array.  B is 33 or less.

Comment: Aside from `s`, are they all unsigned ints?

Comment: Even s is an unsigned int. Unless some character codes go into the negatives? My bad for calling it "string" since it used to be one for the character explicitly instead of the character code.